# How to populate array of custom objects

Tags: arrays, swift, object

```
class abc{
    var name = String()

     init(name:String){
        self.name = name
     }
}

var obj = [abc]()
obj[0] = abc(name:"sun")
obj[1] = abc(name:"sharma")
```

Comment: i am trying to stroe multiple data to create array of  object class

Comment: Even though it's quite obvious in this case what's wrong, you should always explain what is not working and include any compile-/runtime errors in your question along with the expected/actual behaviour. Especially since all questions on SO should be useful for future readers, which won't be the case without these pieces of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about creating an array of objects..

It is really easy

Consider you have two classes, Class A and Class B

```
Class A{
    var name:String

    init(localName: String){
        self.name = localName
    }
}

Class B{
    //here you can create an array of objects of class A
    //this will create an empty array of objects of class A
    var objList = [A]()

    //to add data into this array u can use append 
    func addData(objA: A){
        self.objList.append(objA)
    }

    func displayData(list : [A]){
        for entry in list{    
            print(entry.name)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using implicitly unwrapped optionals unless you have a very good reason to do so (i.e. defining an IBOutlet). `name` can simply be a `String`, there's no reason to make it `String!`... Please also make sure you properly format your code, otherwise it's really hard to read it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are trying to access elements of the array by subscript that don't exist by the time you're trying to access them.

`var obj = [abc]()` just initializes an empty array, so you cannot access its elements by subscript, since it doesn't have any elements yet.

You should use `Array.append` to add new elements to the end of your array.

```
var obj = [Abc]()
obj.append(Abc(name:"sun"))
obj.append(Abc(name:"sharma"))
```

You can also create the array straight away with the elements you want to store in it:

```
var obj = [Abc(name:"sun"),Abc(name:"sharma")]
```

After you have populate the array, you can access its elements in several ways. If you want to iterate through the array, you'll usually want to use the `for...in..` loop:

```
for object in obj {
    print(object.name)
}
```

If you want to access a single element, you can do that using array subscripts, but make sure the index doesn't exceed the array's size before using indexing.

```
let index = 1
if index < array.count { //safe to use index as subscript
    print(obj[index])
}
```

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is upperCamelCase for types (`Abc` instead of `abc`).

Comment: yes it is working now tell how can access this elements